# variable not sent from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am submiting a form to a php page using ajax in order to make a query.
The problem is that the $_POST is empty.
What am I doing wrong here?
Any ideas?

FORM

```
<div id="button_left">
    <form>
    <label>
    <input type="text" class="search" size="30" style="margin-left:20px;" name="epitheto" id="epitheto" placeholder="Επίθετο" />
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση" />
    </label>
    </form>
</div
```

FUNCTION

```
  $(function () {

$('#button_left').on('submit', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'people_name_query_final.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function () {

$("#pelates_last_name_query").slideDown("slow");
   $("#pelates_last_name_query").load( "people_name_query_final.php");


    }
  });

    });

  });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['epitheto'])){

//some code
}
```

Comment: sorry what your problem, is this is your problem, that you are able to submit form even your `POST` is empty. Let me know, means isset function is not doing what you expecting. Thanks

Comment: the problem is that the form is being submitted, the success function is working but the $_POST is empty, so all the code in php is not running.

Comment: see the answer given by me. it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one argument to your success function:

```
      success: function (response) {

$("#pelates_last_name_query").slideDown("slow");
   $("#pelates_last_name_query").html( response);


    }
```

and you will get response from php page....

P.S. Test php page should look like this (or whatever you want for response - you should ECHO something, send some output):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['epitheto'])){

print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

so, vars are sent properly.... (i've tested it right now).

If your php page looks like code you atached/showed us - there is no any output, you didn't printed anything....

Comment: you are right. just tested it also. so the problem is that i cant load the data into #pelates_last_name_query... html(response) is not working

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros, where you test this code? Locally, or on-line? If you test locally -> you need php server installed and turned-on. :), and this must work....

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros, hm... could you send us link, and complete html... Did you checked console?

Comment: i am testing this online.i have noticed in console that when form is submitted the php page shows exactly what it should, but when the page is loaded i get nothing. so strange...

Comment: if you use load() function after ajax request -> you can't see anything, because: about load() -> It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success). So, you send POST data, and GET page... (you will notice in console). Use code i provided with response argument and html(response) in that div.

Answer (score 1):

`<form>` element has `submit` event, `<div>` doesn't.

Change the first line to this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) { // <-- change '#button_left' to 'form'
    // (...) Code
}
```

Comment: the form is being submitted. same results with $('form') or $('#button_left')

Comment: How do you know the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Amit might be correct. You are specifying the incorrect data to submit.

Change `<form>` to `<form id="content">`
Then change your JQuery code accordingly.

```
$('#content').on('submit', function (e) {//rest of your code//}
```

Another possible issue is that the scope on your URL is incorrect.
`url: 'people_name_query_final.php',` will work assuming the PHP script and JQuery are in the same directory.

Also, if you do `print_r($_POST); exit;` in your PHP script you see nothing?

Check the network tab on your browser developer tools to make sure the data is sent properly.

Comment: i am sure that's not the issue. have already tested that, still not working. yes they are in the same directory.

Comment: Just added some more ideas.